# Como salvar notificação?

Tags: android

Estou em uma situação que preciso salvar a notificação mesmo ela sendo aberta, na hora de ler a notificação eu verifico se tem conexão, se tiver ele abre normalmente, se não tiver ele manda uma msg informando que não tem conexão, o problema é que a notificação ja foi aberta e ela some, então queria que nesse caso ela ficasse salva la, até o usuario ler com conexão. como faço?
eu quero que antes de clicar na notificação ele verifique se tem conexao, caso nao tenha joga uma msg, e a notificação nao pode sumir.
Codigo :

public void gerarNotificacao() {

```
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
            ReaderNotificacao.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setLights(Color.WHITE, 500, 500);

    builder.setDefaults(0);
    builder.setTicker("Fadire");
    builder.setContentTitle("Fadire notificação");
    builder.setContentText("Você tem uma nova notícia");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icone);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.icone));
    builder.setContentIntent(p);

    Notification n = builder.build();
    n.vibrate = new long[] { 150, 300, 150, 600 };
    n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    nm.notify(R.drawable.ic_launcher, n);

    try {
        Uri som = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone toque = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, som);
        toque.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Atividade para ler:

```
if(verificaConexao())
lerNotificacoes();
    else {
        Toast.makeText(ReaderNotificacao.this, "Sem conexão, não é possivel ler", 1000).show();
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: A Notificação que você se refere é o Android Toast?

Answer (score 1):

Faltou clareza na sua pergunta. Você se refere a Notification do android?, se for basta você adicionar

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder.setOngoing(true) // o usuario não podera remover a notificaçao.
```

e para cancelar a notificaçao

```
NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);
nMgr.cancel(notifyId);
```

agora se você quer que a notificaçao possa ser removida pelo usuario, basta você relancar a notificaçao assim que clicar nela caso nao tenha conexao.

você pode usar  ***PendingIntent***, com isso você pode inicia uma activity, broadCast ou service dependendo do que desejar, neste caso você pode utilizar um BroadCast entao ficaria assim

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

Neste BroadCast você coloca a verificação se tem internet, se tiver você remove a notificação.

OBS.: BroadCast tem apenas 10 segundos para executar, se passar disso, a aplicação tera um ANR.

Comment: A parte que nao consegui ainda fazer é, ao clicar na notificação verificar a conexão, ou seja como faço para que na hora do clique da notificação ele verifique se tem conexão, caso tenha conexão, ele vai pra outra atividade( que ler a notificação) caso nao tenha conexão, aparece uma msg, porem a notificação nao pode sumir. Então vou colocar o codigo para voce ver e me dizer onde tenho que alterar, obrigado.

Comment: e então, eu faço essa verificação na outra classe, mas a notificação some, como faço para nao sumir, la na outra classe ? a questão é essa

Comment: Com builder.setOngoing(true) não é para sumir.

Comment: eu editei, veja como adicionei o codigo, é dessa forma?